# Adding JComboBox to JTable: ComboBoxes in different rows are not independent

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have a table with a combobox where the user can select a country. I have the problem, that comboBoxes in each row are not independent of each other. When I select an item in row A and then click on the comboBox in row B, the ComboBox B  are automatically set to the same value as comboBox A.

Code:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();   
//Creating the Headers
ArrayList<Adress> adressList = customer.getAdressList(); 
//customer.getAdressList() is an ArrayList, which has been populated from SQL
model.addColumn("ID");
model.addColumn("Country");
//Iterate through Adresses of current Customer and fill JTable
for(Iterator<Adress> iterator = adressList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
Adress adress = iterator.next();
Object[] data = new Object[2];
data[0] = adress.getID();
data[1] = adress.getCountry();
model.addRow(data);
}
//Populate combobox with values from an enum
JComboBox country_comboBox = new JComboBox(CountryEnum.values());
// Set Model, Renderer and Editor
table.setModel(model);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new JComboBoxCountryRenderer(country_comboBox));
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(country_comboBox));
```

and the Renderer:

```
public class JComboBoxCountryRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer{

    CountryEnum country;

    public JComboBoxCountryRenderer(JComboBox comboBox) {
        if (comboBox != null) {
            this.setModel(comboBox.getModel());
            this.setSelectedIndex(comboBox.getSelectedIndex());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable arg0, Object value, boolean arg2, boolean arg3, int arg4,
            int arg5) {
          if (value instanceof CountryEnum) {

                  this.setSelectedItem((CountryEnum) value); 
            }

            return this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `JCombobox` as the renderer, try using as an editor instead...

See [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox) from Oracle.

Comment: so I need to implement my own CellEditor?

Comment: Yes, but you also use a renderer. The default renderer would be just fine.

Comment: Thanks, It works fine without a renderer. But the default renderer won't show the ComboBox, unless the cell is clicked. The problem was that I passed the same model to all rows. It works if I change the renderer line to getAdressen_table().getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new JComboBoxCountryRenderer(new JComboBox(CountryEnum.values())));

Comment: Well, `JComboBox` uses `ComboBoxModel` which contains selection info...